# Building GLEW with Cygwin, X11 - no such file

Tags: c++, cygwin, glew

When trying to build GLEW using Cygwin, I get the following error:

```
$ make
cc -DGLEW_NO_GLU -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude   -o tmp/cygwin/defau
 src/glew.c
In file included from src/glew.c:37:0:
include/GL/glxew.h:97:22: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such fi
compilation terminated.
Makefile:122: recipe for target `tmp/cygwin/default/shared/gl
make: *** [tmp/cygwin/default/shared/glew.o] Error 1
```

What may be causing this?

Comment: Apologies for the poor wording, I should have asked that in a different way. What I meant to ask was, does Cygwin have a substitute for X11 that could be used in building GLEW? I see that Cygwin does not have x11.

Comment: To anybody who has this error, you simply need to use the setup executable that was used for installing Cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/install.html) to download X11 (in the GUI installer package selection section this can be located  by searching "X11")